# Approximate Nearest Neighbour Search with LSH in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nearest-neighbor

I found lot's of discussions and articles that there is possible to find approximate nearest neighbours using Locality Sensitive Hashing (LSH) in 3d spatial coordinates. Unfortunately I was unable to find any real working example, where everything could be done in single copy-paste code.

I am using C# (more specifically Unity) and noticed that some articles stating that approximate NNS can be fast approach for game development. However, I didn't found any real C# implementations yet (or maybe C++ if C# does not exist).

So does anybody know some possible solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use LSH in 3 dimensions? I would suggest you try some tree-based approach, like KD-trees (there are many options). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616445/how-to-best-implement-k-nearest-neighbours-in-c-sharp-for-large-number-of-dimens) is a C# question about KD trees. You could check [ALGLIB](http://www.alglib.net/other/nearestneighbors.php) for KD-trees.

Notice that depending on your dataset, the choice of the data structure differs. You can take a look about some comparisons I had made (in higher dimensions though) [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/2014/04/18/approximate-nearest-neighbors-nn-libraries-in-high-dimensions-flann-vs-cgal-vs-boost/) and [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/2014/12/24/approximate-nearest-neighbors-nn-libraries-in-high-dimensions-rkd-forest-vs-lsh-vs-bbd-tree/).

---

You can check this link
[LSH for Finding Similar Documents from a large number of Documents in C#](https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/lsh-for-finding-similar-documents-from-a-large-number-of-documents-in-c/)
in order to get a C# taste. An interesting question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769949/locality-sensitive-hash-implementation).

---

If you insist on LSH, then since you are dealing with game development, C++ could be also a choice maybe, so here is [E2LSH](http://www.mit.edu/~andoni/LSH/) library.

---

EDIT

ANN has to do with approximate NNS. It uses KD trees and BBD trees. You can check some answers of mine for ANNS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:2411320%20[approximate-nn-searching]).

Comment: Hi Samaras, thanks for message. In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350215/fastest-nearest-neighbor-algorithm) thread I found that [ANN](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/) can be significantly faster than kdtrees just from the account that I would be getting approximate neighbour. This would be exactly what I am interested, as kdtrees for me does not show enough performance and in games it's acceptable to have "approximate" neighbours.

Comment: P.S. I was interested about C++, as I may try to rewrite it to C# if it is not implemented yet...

Comment: I didn't know you wanted ANN! Is the answer OK for you or should I delete it?

Comment: Answer looks ok, you can keep it. But when talking about question, I am curious about these ANN algorithms and if there isn't some algorithms already written in C#, so I could save a lot of time instead of rewriting and reimplementing things from C++. P.S. I am not yet sure if ANN would be the best, as it was made 4 years ago and lots of things could be changed during this time.